# How can I change physical properties for a certain vertex group on a cloth animated object?

Tags: physics, cloth-simulation, vertex-groups

I'm using blender 3.1.
I have a button down shirt, and I want to make some parts of the cloth more rigid, for example the collar. I know I cannot assign several cloth simulations, I could also just apply simulation after sewing the base of the shirt and then add the collar, but it would be more painful and it would not look as good as if it was sewed with the other parts. Are there any ways to achieve a similar result to the one mentioned before?

Comment: One option is the [Pin Group](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/physics/cloth/settings/shape.html) setting of the cloth sim. Create a vertex group and assign or paint the vertices of the collar. Then specify this group in the cloth sim's settings. A weight of 1.0 means that the vertex is pinned and not affected by the cloth sim. You can still move it around with an armature, Empty object, or keyframes.